# bayesian linear regression with given distributions X, y instead of pairs {(X1, y1),..(X100, y100)}

Tags: python, machine-learning, linear-regression, probability, bayesian

I'm wondering if is it possible to model data by knowing only distribution of features (X) and targets (y).
Thus, instead of paired variables {(X1, y1), (X2, y2), .., (Xn, yn)} I know only mean value and standard deviation of both X and y for each category. The dataframe of size (100 rows x 9 columns)  look like this:
[DataFrame with mean, std for X, y per category](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3nNLE.png)

In order to construct typical paired (features, target) dataframe for ML problems. I tried to sample data for each category by 100 samples from given distributions. The results looks as follow:
[Sampled dataframe for each category from given distributins](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xjnxG.png)

However, Im affraid that this wont give reliable insights into model.
Do you have any idea how can I train model for that types of data?

Comment: This question seems not to be coding related and you'd probably get a more satisfying answer here: https://stats.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @Tinu Great! Thanks for suggestion, I didnt know about stats stackexchange.

Comment: Sounds a like a so-called "errors in variables" model, with a Bayesian interpretation. Agreed stats.se is the place for this question.